# In LINQ to perform composed queries is it faster to call existing functions or write the whole query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ado.net, code-reuse

I need to perform queries in a ADO.NET model by using LINQ. 
I have an EF class for the database of my web store `WebStoreEntities` and I need to find all the products, in the table `Products`, that are currently under discount. The instance of `WebStoreEntities` is called `webStoreDB`.

I have already available a method that queries all the product from the database:

```
public IList<Products> GetAllProducts()
{
    return webStoreDB.Products.ToList();
}
```

In order to write a method with signature `IList<Products> GetAllDiscountProducts()` that retrieves all the discounted products, is it faster to write:

```
return webStoreDB.Products.Where(m => Equals(m.discounted, 1)).ToList();
```

or

```
return GetAllProducts().Where(m => Equals(m.discounted, 1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return webStoreDB.Products.Where(m => Equals(m.discounted, 1)).ToList();
```

This is faster because the filtering is done in the database where as

```
return GetAllProducts().Where(m => Equals(m.discounted, 1)).ToList();
```

filtering will be done in memory of the client. Basically LINQ statements issued against IQueriable interface will be translated to SQL when the provider is some relational database.

But if you use LINQ with IEnumerable interface then the query is executed in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Linq uses streaming and deferred execution so until the `ToList()` is called your query hasn't  been executed in your database context.

(You should know you're using linq-to-entities here so your linq is composed into an sql query and then executed)

`GetAllProducts()` calls `ToList()`:

At this point the sql is sent to your database, executed and then it returns in memory objects. These in-memory objects are then filtered by this part:
 `.Where(m => Equals(m.discounted, 1)).ToList();`
(And this is part now Linq-To-Objects)

It is a **HUGE** snag because it will Execute an sql query to return ALL products (=>`SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS`). And if you have a million products, they'll all be returned in memory!!

I recommend HRH Jon Skeets [Edulinq series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx), it should give you a good understanding of deferred execution. Especially the [article on](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx) `.Where();`

Comment: Oops oops. I didn't see that!